# Plot a vertical line using datetime.time and axvline

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I am trying to use the axvline function to plot datetime.time values and seeing this error. please help.

Here is the code:

```
import datetime as dt 
from datetime import datetime 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

i='wpt' 
x = [datetime.time(12,10), datetime.time(12, 15)] 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex = True, figsize = (12,9), constrained_layout = True)

axs[i].axvline(x[0], color = 'lightskyblue', ls = '--', lw = 1)
```

When i run the code, i get the following error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.time'
```

I checked online and found no solution that uses axvline with `datetime.time`

Comment: How should the plot interpret the `datetime`? Convert it to epoch time using [**`datetime.timestamp`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Comment: Replace x with [dt.time(12,10), dt.time(12, 15)] and your plotting line with axs[0] (axs['wpt'] doesn't mean anything there).

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib expects a numeric x coordinate, not a datetime object.
You need to convert the time to a number, e.g. by using the matplotlib.dates.date2num function:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

axs[i].axvline(mdates.date2num(datetime.combine(date.today(), x[0])), ...)
```

This will convert the time to a floating point number representing the number of days since January 1, 0001. Matplotlib will then use its date plotting machinery to format the axis appropriately.
Note that I used datetime.combine here to convert the time into a full datetime object by adding today's date.

Comment: I just want to know if it would be possible to plot the time only on the axis rather than the epoch time for example in this case plotting a verticle line at 12:10 and displaying the same using the plot